# Recursion in closures Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, closures

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def memoize(limit, *, message = 'Limit exceded'):
    count = 0
    def inner(func):
        cache = {}
        def wrapped(number):
            nonlocal count
            if count < limit:
                if number not in cache:
                    cache[number] = func(number)
                count += 1
                return cache[number]
            print(message)
        return wrapped
    return inner

@memoize(5)
def fat(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 1
    return x * fat(x - 1)
```

In theory the algorithm should receive a number that would set a storage limit of the results in a cache, instead of raising an exception I simply show the message that was passed or the default ("Limit exceded") in case the limit number in the cache is reached . The problem is that it only runs the program only once and shows the message, but where is the error ???

Comment: Have you tried printing data/conditional results/etc at strategic locations to see what my be happening?

Comment: Yes, in a single function call the count value goes to 50

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here. Can you edit the question to give an example, with inputs, expected outputs, and desired outputs?

Comment: Do you want it to ***stop*** when the cache reaches the limit or when the function has been called `limit` times?

Comment: More specifically do you want it to stop when the *recursion depth* reaches `limit` or total number of call's (recursive calls plus *initial* calls with different arguments)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't setting a limit on the size of the cache, but on the number of calls to the wrapper:

```
if number not in cache:
    cache[number] = func(number)
count += 1
```

In other words, you increment `count` whether the number was already in the cache or not. To fix that, you just need to indent that increment.

---

On top of that, the `count` doesn't get reset for each new cache, because the only place you set it to `0` is in outer function:

```
def memoize(limit, *, message = 'Limit exceded'):
    count = 0
    def inner(func):
        cache = {}
```

To fix that, you need to move the `count = 0` from `memoize` to `inner`. (Or, if you prefer, add a `nonlocal count` and reset it with `count = 0` in `inner`, but that's just extra work for the same effect.)

---

But an even simpler fix to both of these problem is to get rid of `count` entirely. You're trying to count whether you've hit the storage limit in the cache? Just check `if len(cache) < limit:`.

Comment: I removed counter and am checking the size of the cache as you said but it still does not work

Comment: @ThiagoLuizS Well, it's quite possible that your code has more bugs than the two I fixed. But they get increasingly hard to find when I still don't know what you're trying to achieve and what exactly is happening instead; only the most obvious bugs can be uncovered blindly.